# Change marker's type after it's creation

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm using Gmap.NET in winforms and I'm trying to figure out proper way to change marker's type (pin style) after marker is created. I'm making application with quite a lot of different overlays and eventually they will run out unique markers.

I tried looking through library, but couldn't find possibility of that. So far my best solution seems to backup markers positions, clear markers and remake them again. But this solution feels far from ideal. Maybe you guys have any better ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach here imo is to derive a CustomMarker and let this type be aware of all the (graphical) states it needs to display. All the marker types provided mostly only differ in the image they display. That way you avoid the hassle of recreating markers over and over again.

Comment: Eh, kinda wished marker property was made public out of the box. So it seems it will require some work.

Comment: Have a look at [the arrow marker sample](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/master/Demo.WindowsForms/CustomMarkers/GMarkerArrow.cs) in the sources, it demos how to make properties of your marker publicly available.